Vertical direction of the right click context menu options
When the right-click context menu opens, it by default tries to open downward as a drawer from the position of your cursor. When the space below the cursor is not adequate, it flips and opens above. This is now the common expected behaviour of these menus.
The menu action placements are based on mouse travel, meaning more common actions at the top. Should these actions flip if the menu draws upward due to lack of space at the bottom?
The question came to mind when I was correcting spelling mistakes in one program where when menu opened up, I had a long travel to spelling suggestions.


People really easily get used to the exact layout of a menu, meaning they don't so much read what the menu says as they remember "the entry midway down the list that starts with G". Flipping it means that they'd have to re-parse all options to find the one they'd need, which nullifies any speed gain which flipping the options would achieve. It also doesn't help that it's a bit unpredictable whether a menu will go up or down before you summon it.
That said: For a spelling mistakes block, this argument doesn't necessarily hold as it's dynamically populated. There may be a case for it to switch position - there also may be a case for it to be disjointed from the main context menu. Google Docs for example has the correction on hover, rather than on right-click.
It's also worth pointing out that just because something would be better in theory, it doesn't mean it'd be accepted by users. For example, ring menus are superior to the classic context menu as every item is exactly the same distance away from the cursor, but outside of games and a handful of apps (like blender), it's practically never used as it doesn't meet the user expectation of what a context menu should look like and ends up causing more confusion.

I agree with keeping the order for mental-space-memory-reasons. Honorable mention to 3d studios (superior) 20 year old quad-menus, that opens in four directions grouped by categories, and can repeat last command with the blue box and a 2px mouse movement: https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/cdn-cgi/image/width=850/uploads/users/403/posts/28380/image/3d-mini-house-edit-poly.jpg
